# Excel Import VBA: Run-time 3075 Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I am getting a missing operator error in the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Sample.Number, Sample.SampleDate, BOD.BOD_Concentration_IN, BOD.BOD_Concentration_OUT, TSS.TSS_Influent, TSS.TSS_Effluent 
     FROM SampleInformation as Sample 
          INNER JOIN BOD_Data as BOD ON Sample.Number = BOD.Number 
          INNER JOIN TSS_Data as TSS ON Sample.Number = TSS.Number 
     WHERE (DATEPART('m',Sample.SampleDate) = DATEPART('m',#1/13/2016 12:01:00 PM#)) 
     AND (DATEPART('yyyy',Sample.SampleDate) = DATEPART('yyyy',#1/13/2016 12:01:00 PM#)) ORDER BY Sample.SampleDate
```

I eliminated the "WHERE" clause and still got the error, so it must be in the join.

Can anyone see what I am missing here? Thanks!

Comment: ... and you could use the following:
     WHERE (MONTH(SampleDate) = MONTH(#1/13/2016 12:01:00 PM#)) 
     AND (YEAR(SampleDate) = YEAR(#1/13/2016 12:01:00 PM#))

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, your comment looks like the right answer. If you put it below (as an answer), then Mr. OReilly can mark this question "answered" and other SO users won't spend time working on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out you are missing ( ) around the 'FROM' clause... try the following:

And BTW, 'Number' does not need to be enclosed in brackets (although it is a reserved word)

```
SELECT Sample.Number, Sample.SampleDate, BOD.BOD_Concentration_IN, BOD.BOD_Concentration_OUT, TSS.TSS_Influent, TSS.TSS_Effluent 
 FROM (SampleInformation AS Sample 
       INNER JOIN BOD_Data AS BOD ON Sample.Number = BOD.Number) 
       INNER JOIN TSS_Data AS TSS ON Sample.Number = TSS.Number
 WHERE (DATEPART('m',Sample.SampleDate) = DATEPART('m',#1/13/2016 12:01:00 PM#)) 
 AND (DATEPART('yyyy',Sample.SampleDate) = DATEPART('yyyy',#1/13/2016 12:01:00 PM#)) ORDER BY Sample.SampleDate
```

Comment: Wayne, you were close (see edits in your answer), and your original post got me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you did exactly what I did ... used the query builder to create the proper syntax, then add criteria.  As for your edit, I rejected it because the only difference you have now is that you enclosed some of the field names in brackets [].... which I also determined didn't cause the issue, so I didn't use them.  Glad it's working!!

Comment: Okay, fair enough! Thanks for your input.